# Wordpress: Saving Form Data and POST external

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, content-management-system, crm

*I'm creating a Booking form in Wordpress which will send the data to an external CRM (Airship in this case) whilst also storing the data inside the Wordpress CMS that can then be emailed automatically.*

Currently I've tried Contact Form 7 and a few other plugins, but this requires its own `action="/?page_id=1327&preview=true#wpcf7-f1326-p1327-o1"` (just as a page preview whilst building).

Airship CRM also has it's own `action="http://atwbar.com/linkitajax.php"` required to submit data.

Any suggestions/advice would be **HUGELY** appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

when I want to save some special data, process a form to a crm or just redirect all my forms, I use the Contact form 7 hook : `wpcf7_before_send_mail`
Here is an example to redirect any form to a page (extract from an utility plugin I've done, so, don't take care about unset and session lines, options...).

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'mail_send_redirection');

function mail_send_redirection($contactform){
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if($options['_redirect_all_forms'] == 'false' && $contact_form->prop( 'redirection_settings' ) == 'false'){
         return;
     }

      $redirection_form_id = $contact_form->prop( 'redirection_settings' );

       $redirection_page_id = (empty($redirection_form_id)) ? $options['_thank_you_url'] : $redirection_form_id;
       $nonce = wp_create_nonce('redirect-user-action');

        if($contact_form->prop( 'redirection_message' ) != ''){
              $args = array(
                  'html' => false,
                  'exclude_blank' => false );

              $message = wpcf7_mail_replace_tags( $contact_form->prop( 'redirection_message' ), $args );

                 unset($_SESSION['bcf7u_nonce']);
                 unset($_SESSION['bcf7u_message']);
                 unset($_SESSION['bcf7u_pageid']);

                 $_SESSION['_nonce'] = $nonce;
                 $_SESSION['_pageid'] = $redirection_page_id;
                 $_SESSION['_message'] = $message;


         }

         $contact_form->skip_mail = false;

         $contact_form->set_properties(
           array(
            'additional_settings' => "on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('" . get_permalink($redirection_page_id) . "/?nonce=" . $nonce . "');\""));

}
```

To save a form field, just use update_post_meta.

There are other method to send a request base on wp_ajax_no_priv_{$action} action and js.

Tell me if it's helps you, or if you need some more hints !

Comment: Thanks for this! About to try it out and will come straight back with the result! Thom